# CSS bring element to the back of page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a rather unique issue, I can't find any information on how to fix it.

Here is a picture:

[image: no desription]

I want the credit card input box moved to the back, if I'm explaining myself correctly.

I am using http://creditcardjs.com/ and Bootstrap 3

Comment: share you piece of code

Comment: You're looking for [z-index](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcssref%2Fpr_pos_z-index.asp&ei=Gh7GU67WOojd8AWA9YLoDg&usg=AFQjCNGo5mGU8EL1dtgS5oJ1TZIetDBRjA&sig2=s-uYfbxMgay03XCiOlMcWg&bvm=bv.71126742,d.dGc)

Comment: move back in the sense ??.. you can lower ur z-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The z-index proprety of the element you want to move back must be greater than the z-index of the element you want to remain in the front.

You can specify the z-index from css.

Here's more about using z-index: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move your credit card block back then reduce z-index.

but i think you want it at the center of page as shown in the link.Now in your case block is on navigation bar.
for that add  css to your block.
                                  `position:relative;                                                                margin:200px;`